# How to use a static constant (declared in parent class ) via a child class ( inherited class )

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have something like this :

```
class ParentClass
{
public static const ON_SOME_EVT:String = "onSomeEvent" ;
....
}


class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
 ....
}



main()
{

trace( ChildClass.ON_SOME_EVT ) ; //<< compiler error on doing this
//1119: Access of possibly undefined property ABC through a reference with static type           Class.



}
```

Then how should i achieve this. I want to access the constant via child class but not the parent class.

Thanks.

Comment: When you inherit from `ParentClass` you are already coupled to it. So why do not directly use `ParentClass.ON_SOME_EVENT` in the subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is just to re-declare your static const in the child class and reference the ParentClass.ON_SOME_EVT.

```
class ParentClass
{
public static const ON_SOME_EVT:String = "onSomeEvent" ;
....
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
public static const ON_SOME_EVT:STring = ParentClass.ON_SOME_EVT;
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[static vars can't be inherited](http://wonderfl.net/c/lLor/read)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do `trace(ON_SOME_EVT);` in the ChildClass, because the constant is inherited too if I'm not mistaken.
But the constant is a static member of `ParentClass` so outside of the inheritance tree you cannot avoid using `ParentClass.ON_SOME_EVT`. Why don't you want to use that?